# If $x$, $y$ and $z$ are random numbers between 0 and 1, what is the probability that $x z + y(1-z) > w$ for some $0<w<1$?

Tags: integration, random-variables

Suppose $x, y, z$ are all independent random variables drawn from a uniform distribution from 0 to 1. What is the probability that $x z + y(1-z)>w$ for some $w$ in the interval $0<w<1$? This probability will depend on $w$.

Some things I think I know about the solution:

1. In the limit $w\rightarrow0$, the probability $P(x z + y(1-z)>w)$ will tend to 1
2. In the limit $w\rightarrow1$, the probability $P(x z + y(1-z)>w)$ will tend to 0
3. When $w=1/2$ the probability $P(x z + y(1-z)>w)$ will also equal $1/2$, due to symmetry

Naively, I assumed that the solution would be $P(x z + y(1-z)>w) = 1-w $ which satifies these boundary conditions, however a Monte Carlo simulation I performed suggests that this is not correct and that the true function is sigmoid-like. See the graph below:[[image: a plot of <span class=]$p$ against $w$ for both my simple Monte Carlo model and the (incorrect) model $p=1-w$, showing the discrepancies between the two." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Oo3M.png)

I guess that finding the correct solution requires finding the volume by integrating over $x, y, z$ , but I am struggling to do this, since the limits of the areas to be integrated over themselves depend on $w$. Also, if it is straightforward to generalise to non-uniform distributions of $x,y,z$, I would be interested to know.

Comment: Your guess is correct. Can you write down the triple integral over dx,dy,dz with the correct non constant limits? I'd be very surprised if that's unsolvable.

Comment: I too would be surprised if its unsolvable! I am finding it hard to find the correct limits (too many dimensions to easily visualise!) but if I find something I'll post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left[ZX + (1-Z)Y > w\right] &= \int_0^1\int_0^1 \int_0^1\mathbf 1_{zx + (1-z)y > w}dzdydx\\
&= \int_0^1\int_0^1 \int_0^1\mathbf 1_{(x-y)z > w-y}dzdydx\\
&= \int_0^w\int_0^w \underbrace{\int_0^1\mathbf 1_{(x-y)z > w-y}dz}_{=0}dydx + \int_0^w\int_w^1 \int_0^1\mathbf 1_{(x-y)z > w-y}dzdydx + \int_w^1\int_0^w \int_0^1\mathbf 1_{(x-y)z > w-y}dzdydx + \int_w^1\int_w^1 \underbrace{\int_0^1\mathbf 1_{(x-y)z > w-y}dz}_{=1}dydx\\
&= \int_0^w\int_w^1 \int_0^1\mathbf 1_{(x-y)(1-z) > w-y}dzdydx + \int_w^1\int_0^w \int_0^1\mathbf 1_{(x-y)z > w-y}dzdydx + (1-w)^2\\
&= \int_0^w\int_w^1 \int_0^1\mathbf 1_{(x-y)z < x-w}dzdydx + \int_w^1\int_0^w \int_0^1\mathbf 1_{(x-y)z > w-y}dzdydx + (1-w)^2\\
&= \int_0^w\int_w^1 \int_0^1\left(\mathbf 1_{(x-y)z < x-w} + \mathbf 1_{(y-x)z > w-x}\right)dzdydx + (1-w)^2\\
&= 2\int_w^1 \int_0^w \int_0^1 \mathbf 1_{(x-y)z > w-y}dzdydx + (1-w)^2
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\int_w^1\int_0^w \int_0^1\mathbf 1_{(x-y)z > w-y}dzdydx = &= \int_w^1 \int_0^w \frac{x-w}{x-y}\mathrm d y\mathrm dx\\
&= \int_w^1 (x-w)\left[-\ln(x-y)\right]_0^w \mathrm dx\\
&= \int_w^1 (x-w)\left(\ln(x) - \ln (x-w)\right)\mathrm dx\\
&= \left[\frac14 x\left((2x-4w)\ln x + 4w - x\right) - \frac14 (x-w)^2 \left(2 \ln (x-w) - 1\right)\right]_w^1\\
&= \left(w - \frac14-\frac14(1-w)^2(2\ln(1-w)-1) + \frac12 w^2\ln w - \frac34 w^2\right)
\end{align}

Finally,

\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left[ZX + (1-Z)Y > w\right] &= w^2 \ln w - (1-w)^2 \ln (1-w) + \frac32 (1-w)^2 - \frac32 w^2 + 2w - \frac12
\end{align}

Comment: Wow. A surprising amount of work. But the [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+w%5E2+ln%28+w+%29+-+%281-w%29%5E2+ln%281-w%29+%2B+3%2F2+%281-w%29%5E2+-+3%2F2+w%5E2+%2B+2w+-+1%2F2+and+1-w+for+w%3D0+...1) is what OP got with Monte Carlo. ***+1***

Comment: Great, thank you! Yes, the calculation was much more involved than I was expecting going into it. As Kurt G. points out, your solution fits the Monte Carlo perfectly. One thing: I am not familiar with the bold '1' notation (as in $\mathbf{1}_{(x-y)z>w} etc.$). Does this kind of notation have a name and what does it indicate?

Comment: this notation is used for the indicator function https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Indicator_function